# "correspondence with" vs "correspondence between"

Tags: word-usage, style

Meaning "correspondence" as "letters" or "exchange of letters" (not similarity), which sentence would be more appropriate (may be there are only subtle differences in style):

> 1. The correspondence of A with B.
> 2. The correspondence between A and B.

I've seen also:

> 3. The A-B correspondence.

Are they interchangeable? I mean when both persons write, not the case "from A to B" or vice versa.

Also, is it possible in this context replace "correspondence" with "letters" (in every sentence)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word correspondence is defined as the **exchange** of letters. Furthermore, if you look up the word **exchange** it is defined as the giving of something for something else (in this case letters).

By this definition there is an **exchange**  of letters in both sentences regardless of whether you use **with** or **between**

In other words, the use of the word correspondence, by definition, already tells us that letters go from A to B and visa versa.

In the sentences you have provided you cant substitute letters for correspondence because correspondence refers to the exchange and not to what is being exchanged.

if you want to show that a letter is being sent in one direction (A to B) then you can use the preposition **to**

**e.g. A wrote **to** B.**

if you want to show that A and B both exchange letters then you can say:

**A and B wrote to each other**.

In your original sentence the use of **between** probably gives a stronger idea of reciprocity , but that's just my opinion.

Comment: Ok, I can't substitute correspondence with letters meaning exchange, the process of exchanging, but, in the wide sense, can I say "the letters of A with B" or "the letters between A and B"?

Comment: Not in the examples you have given. However, you could say The letters between A and B were very rude (describing the letters). The letters of A with B doesn't  really make sense or sound natural to me.

Comment: And what about The A-B correspondence? For example, I saw The Einstein-Freud Correspondence,  meaning possibly "exchange", but I'd understand "letters" too. And what about letters? I think it's possible to say The A-B letters, or A and B's letters, but which is more formal or more colloquial?

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean. by the A-B correspondence.  I think that if for example the Einstein-Freud   correspondence is a collection of letters in a museum then YES you can say letters.in place of correspondence  e.g. We went to the Science museum and saw the Einstein-Freud letters. (or correspondence) The letters here would be examples of the correspondence that went on between these two scientists.

Comment: Why, in your inicial answer, you defined "correspondence" as "the exchange of letter" only? I understand it as the process of writing and sending letters, not the letters themselves. But I see in this definition by Oxford Lerner's Dictionary that "correspondence" is defined also as "the letters a person sends and receives": https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/correspondence?q=correspondence

Comment: The letters someone sends and receives is the same thing as an exchange.  The word correspondence is related to letters and in this case the exchange of letters (backwards and forwards from one person to another.) Correspondence relates to letters or emails and by definition includes the word exchange which means the changing or swapping of one thing for another. (in this case the thing is letters).

Comment: My pleasure.  It was a good question and difficult to explain over the internet.